# BCP woes: Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

Tags: sql-server, bulk-insert, bcp

I have a table defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IpMetadata](
    [StartIp] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EndIp] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CountryCode] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [ProxyType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProxyDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IspName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [MobileCarrier] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MobileCarrierCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Latitude] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Longitude] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Region] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [GmtOffset] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SupportsDaylightSavings] [char](10) NULL,
    [MetroCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AddressCount] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_IpMetadata] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [StartIp] ASC,
        [EndIp] ASC
    )
)
```

I have a UTF-8 encoded sampling file (D:\data\ipsnip.csv) with tab-delimited, CRLF terminated rows to insert into this table like so:

```
#start-ip   end-ip  edge-two-letter-country proxy-type  proxy-description   isp-name    mobile-carrier  mobile-carrier-code edge-latitude   edge-longitude  edge-postal-code    edge-city   edge-region edge-country    edge-gmt-offset edge-in-dst edge-metro-code address-count
0   0   **                  0   0   0   0   reserved    *** *** +9999   n   -1  0
1   255 **                  0   0   0   0   reserved    *** *** +9999   n   -1  254
256 16777215    **                  0   0   0   0   reserved    *** *** +9999   n   -1  16776959
16777216    16777343    au                  0   -37.7596    145.134 3106    templestowe vic aus +1000   n   36211   127
16777344    16777407    au                  0   -37.7596    145.134 3106    templestowe vic aus +1000   n   36211   63
16777408    16777471    au                  0   -37.7596    145.134 3106    templestowe vic aus +1000   n   36211   63
16777472    16778239    cn          chinanet fujian province network        0   26.0786 119.298 350000  fuzhou  35  chn +800    n   156115  767
16778240    16779263    au          big red group       0   -37.8387    144.99  3141    south yarra vic aus +1000   n   36206   1023
16779264    16781311    cn          chinanet guangdong province network     0   30.6611 104.082 510000  guangzhou   44  chn +800    n   156196  2047
16781312    16785407    jp          i2ts inc.       0   35.6838 139.754 100-0001    tokyo   13  jpn +900    n   -1  4095
```

I run the BCP command like so:

```
bcp MyDatabase.dbo.IpMetadata in D:\data\ipsnip.csv -F2 -Slocalhost -n -T
```

I get a response back like so:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

BCP copy in failed
```

I have tried explicitly specifying the column and row terminators.  I have tried using unicode column definitions.  I have tried changing the line ends to LF instead of CRLF.  I have tried replacing the field terminators with semicolons/ pipes.  I have tried `-n` and`-N`.  I don't know what else to try.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: I would start by verifying the integrity of the file - for instance loading it into Excel and checking that all rows have the same number of tab characters. Do you need to escape any tab characters?

Comment: there's 187 tabs, 11 rows... it divides evenly, so that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: Does column 1 really have a hash in it? Have you tried with only 1 row of data? Or -w for unicode characters (I assume you checked that but thought it's worth mentioning)

Comment: The header column has a hash in it, but nothing else does.  The original file has 13M records, so I figured I'd use a handful to test with, but I haven't reduced it to just one row.  I'll try it out and report if that makes any difference.

Comment: I have reduced to four lines and it still doesn't work. There seems to be an issue with either `-n` or `-N` parameter when using your data. It doesn't seem to be native UTF-8 at all. I tried saving the file as UTF-8, UTF-16 with and without BOM, native UTF and even UTF-16 big endian, but bcp doesn't seem to care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the `-n` and the `-N` are *not* what I wanted;  I had assumed it used the db metadata to implicitly convert the incoming data, but it looks like it's expecting binary data with that.

I changed it to `-c` and it worked without issue.

Comment: Why was it not what you wanted?  Is `-c` required for tables that contain character columns?

Comment: it's used when dealing with characters in general, i.e. text files.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob's comment under the question helped me!

> Does column 1 really have a hash in it? Have you tried with only 1 row of data? > Or `-w` for unicode characters (I assume you checked that but thought it's worth mentioning) – [Jacob H](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/125215/jacob-h) [Jun 7 '17 at 14:37](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175654/bcp-woes-unexpected-eof-encountered-in-bcp-data-file#comment340192_175654)

Adding `-w` in the code helped to import my files.